# Is a body travelling along a straight line 1 dimension, 2 dimension or 3 dimension?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

Suppose a body is travelling along a straight line. In textbooks, we learnt that anybody travelling along a straight line is one dimension. But in a two dimension plane, if the body is travelling along a straight line inclined to the horizontal axis, we say that the body is travelling in a plane or in two dimensions. Or in other words, we can consider the body to move in a superposition along both the horizontal and vertical components. But what I want to ask is since the body is travelling a straight line, shouldn't we consider the body to be moving in 1d?

Comment: Imagine changing coordinates such that it now is travelling along only 1 axis, what would you say now?

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. But how would you justify the fact that every body traveling along a straight line is traveling in 1d??

Comment: We can always choose the coordinate system, so that one of its axes is along the direction of motion.

Comment: You are moving within three dimensions, on a one dimensional line. Another example is the span of 2 vectors;  the span is a 2 dimensional plane  embedded in three dimensional space

Comment: @jensenpaull If the object is truly moving in one dimension, I'd say the motion is one dimensional. If a physicist chooses to use a "bad" set of coordinates to describe that motion, then that's on them. But the second coordinate is strictly redundant information. You could calculate the $y$ coordinate knowing only the $x$ coordinate given $y=mx+b$.

Answer (score 3):

In "the real world," any object only ever moves in three dimensions (at least, in any situation we have ever observed).

However, it is sometimes useful to make an *idealization* or *approximation* that an object only moves in one or two dimensions. The advantage of this idealization is that it simplifies the description of the motion, since we have fewer dimensions to keep track of. The disadvantage is that we have necessarily lost some information. This tradeoff is worth it, making the idealization useful, if we only care about the motion in one or two of the dimensions.

For example, consider a train. While a real train jostles and bumps in directions perpendicular to the track, from the point of view of a passenger, the only motion that is relevant is the motion along the direction of the track.

Therefore, from the passenger's point of view, it is reasonable to approximate the train's motion as being purely along the track, and ask questions like "if the train is traveling this fast, how long will it take to reach that destination," without worrying about sideways motion.

From the point of view of an engineer who builds trains, however, the train's sideways motion is critically important to understand and minimize, for passenger safety and comfort, and for energy efficiency and the smooth operation of the train.

In your specific example, I would say that the distinction comes down to whether you would like to model the object as being capable of moving in a direction perpendicular to the line it is traveling on. If so, you need to consider multiple dimensions, even if the object is only traveling in a line. If not, then using one dimension to describe the object's motion is appropriate. In other words, you decide what *degrees of freedom* you need to model the system, based on making the model as simple as possible, without overly restricting the possible behavior.

To summarize, what allows us to say that an object is effectively only traveling in one or two dimensions, is *context.*

Answer (score 0):

After all, it's about forces that influence the body. We have a one-dimensional system exactly when the influence is exclusively along the direction of movement of the body. Of course, I can make the body-force system into a two- or even three-dimensional system by choosing an unfavourable coordinate system. This also makes it clear that a two-dimensional system is one in which the body or bodies move along a plane and the existing force centres are also located on this plane.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the body is in each case 1D, 2D or 3D travelling along the  vector $~\vec s ~$

with

$$\vec s_1= s\,\begin{bmatrix}
     1 \\
     0 \\
     0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\quad,\vec s_2= \frac{s}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\begin{bmatrix}
     x \\
     y \\
     0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\quad,\vec s_3= s\,\frac{s}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\begin{bmatrix}
     x \\
     y \\
     z \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$

where s is the generalized coordinate

: